# Removing router bit that is stuck with damaged shaft

Tags: tools, powertools, routers

I got this router from a family member for free but the bit is stuck. It's waaaay over tightened. Trying to get it out just damages the shaft (which I already managed to do). What is the best approach to loosen this and get the bit out?

Thanks!

EDIT: Following several suggestions, I tried using the pin with a bigger wrench. I tried before but only with the supplied wrench. Here is the result. It is waaay over tightened or there is some other reason why I can't loosen it. That's is way I asked for help here.

EDIT 2: thanks for all the suggestions. I will try the different approaches and report back.

[image]

[image]

Comment: How did you damage the shaft?

Comment: looks like you used an improperly fitting wrench

Comment: I damaged the shaft when I tried to get the over tightened bit out using the wrench supplied with the tool. I suspect that the previous user tightened it with a larger wrench and now it's way overtightened.

Comment: I'm confused as to how exactly the shaft was damaged in that area. You're not supposed to be doing anything to that piece of the shaft when tightening or loosening the nut which clamps the bit.

Comment: Accordingly to the instructions, there are two ways to tighten and loosen bits. 1) Using the little pin and one of the supplied wrenches at the nut. 2) Using two supplied wrenches. One at the shaft and one at the nut. So according to the instructions, using a wrench at the shaft is one of the methods to tighten/loosen. I tried the pin but without any success so I tried two wrenches afterwards.

Comment: Two wrench is when the shaft is shaped for a wrench.  You have a retaining pin and a button (red) to engage (lock) the shaft.  I see Kris has already ans how to do this.  Just use a long handle wrench on the nut while the pin is engaged in the hole in the shaft.

Comment: I tried again using the button with a larger wrench (about 12''). See picture in my edited post... There is a reason why I got the router for free.

Comment: Stick an allen wrench in the hole.  And make sure you're turning the nut in the right direction.

Comment: Based on the 1st pic, it looks like the housing that holds the shaft-lock pin has cracked. Based on the 2nd pic, you've damaged the shaft. Most importantly - that shaft will be spinning around 20,000 RPM and is now out of balance due to removed/rearranged metal. **BE VERY CAUTIOUS** using this router. Inspect it _FREQUENTLY_ for further damage. Be aware that vibrations _could_ cause further damage to the shaft-lock housing. If a piece were to break off while in use it would become a missile going in a random direction. [Cont...]

Comment: ... Routers are very efficient at removing wood. They are _far_ more efficient at removing meat from fingers. Since this is a new-to-you router that, presumably, you've never used, you're not familiar with the vibration level, so you won't know what feels "wrong". Extra vibrations _could_ cause enough damage for bit to come out at some point throwing a large hunk of sharp, spinning metal at you, your work, or an onlooker. In a desire to have you around to ask further questions, **PLEASE USE EXTREME CAUTION WHEN USING A DAMAGED ROUTER** and consider keeping it on the shelf as a souvenir.

Comment: It *might* be possible to replace the shaft if you can find an undamaged replacement part.  Personally I would bring it to a professional for that sort of thing.  Might cost a bit of money, but possibly cheaper than replacing the entire router.

Comment: I see you damaged the housing (which holds the chuck stop) while attempting to free this nut.  Examine the thread carefully, and see if you're going the wrong way or not for starters. Some are reverse threaded, so that they "tighten" while running against the wood.  I would try heating the nut, as the metal will expand slightly.  It doesn't take much to heat it up, and you don't want to heat the shaft.  Otherwise, some WD-40, and left for a day, will most likely free it.  Given how much force has been used on it, it is possible to bend the shaft, creating a wobble, therefore, an uneven cut.

Answer (score 7):

While the other answer is correct in normal conditions - that is the purpose of the pin.

I would use a bar that fits into the hole in that shaft and a properly fitting wrench as if it has been overtightened it will need some force to undo it.

Using the normal mechanism relies on the strength of the aluminum casting which may break under these conditions. And looking at the first picture it looks as if that casting is already cracked so take care.

Answer (score 5):

[image]

Rotate shaft until the hole (red arrow)aligns with the pin.  (Yellow arrow)Push orange button to interlock pin with hole in shaft. Use appropriate size wrench to turn locking nut(purple arrow). After a couple turns the bit should slip out of the end of the shaft .

Comment: Thanks! I actually tried this without success. Not I went back with a bigger wrench and broke the pin holding thing. This thing is seriously over-tightened and I am not sure what to do next.

Comment: Try heating it with a heat gun. Use some penetrating oil. Try turning in opposite direction.

Comment: Agree with Kris, try turning in the opposite direction.  You may be tighten the nut, not removing the nut.

Answer (score 2):

Looking closely at the threads that are showing it appears that it  may be a reverse thread. (*counter clockwise, it is difficult to tell for sure. I do not know why it would be, neither my dewalt nor my bosch are.*)

It may also  be that the collet is cross threaded.

Since the shaft is already damaged:

Clamp the router **FIRMLY** to a bench, clamp the shaft **FIRMLY** in a large pair of locking pliers (*vise grips*) and use a LARGE adjustable wrench (*crescent wrench*) with **long pipe over the handle** on the collet to give you leverage. When you start to turn the crescent wrench, the vise grips will turn until they hit the bench and then you can start to use leverage/muscle.

AND as Freeman stated, **the future use of the router is questionable.**

A note on penetrates: PB Blaster is a much superior penetrate.

Comment: +1 that picture definitely makes that look left-hand-threaded (or cross threaded as you say) to me.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like it is very tightly stuck, in which case similar methods could work as with removing stuck nuts in general:

1. Penetrating lubricant, such as WD40. Spray it into the nut threads and let it soak in for 15 minutes before trying to loosen the nut.
2. Heat: use a hot air gun to warm up the nut, it should expand and be easier to remove.
3. Impact: the idea is to mount the bigger piece (the router) into a sturdy vice, put a well-fitting wrench on the smaller piece (nut) and then give a whack to the wrench with a hammer. The sudden impact will deliver a large force that can break up whatever corrosion is holding the nut up. In your case, mounting the shaft to a vice is probably difficult, but you can experiment with some kind of strong pin in the hole to stop it from rotating.

Comment: Note however that the "whack" method might damage the bearings or make the existing crack in the casing much worse. Try the other two methods first.